# How do I repeat a gradient color ramp?

Tags: materials, uv, node-editor

I have a gradient on a cube with a color ramp. In the picture below you can see the color ramp is repeated just once. I would like to find a way how to repeat it 5 or 10 times. I could do this on the color ramp it self of course, but I prefer to it with a node setup.

[image]

After repeating the gradient, it should look something like this, a multiple loop of a color ramp.

[image]

Comment: You could take the modulo of the vector's components and then combine them back

Comment: do you mean that no added node is necessary ?

Comment: Separate the Generated vector input into x, y and z, then take the modulo of the x, by using a math node, the combined the x, y and z into a vector, which you can use to map the texture.

Comment: could you add a picture , so i can see what you mean ? thanks

Comment: Not now, sorry - it's pretty late already

Answer (score 13):

You can use a *Color Ramp* node and a *Modulo* converter node to achieve this result.

Set up your nodes like this:

[image: Gradient Nodes]

And this is the result:

[image: Result]

What you are doing is you are making the *Color Ramp* node tell what color, and then you are mapping it using the *Mapping* node, and repeating it with the *Modulo* node. This makes it fully editable, you can change the color ramp, and the resulting texture will repeat endlessly.

[image: Editability GIF]

Comment: i wanted to try this solution , i clicked shift A , and searched for a modulo node, but that is not in any list . where do i find it ?

Comment: It's a generic math node.  'Convertor->Math'.  Click 'Add' to see a list of operations the node implements.

Comment: Sorry, yes, the Math node can be changed to many different operations, but you have to add the plain default one first.

Comment: before i start figuring this out , let me ask a bit more about this solution , i see you did this easy with a black and white gradient, an just moved the slider a bit , and there you go.  but what if this is a more complex gradient color ramp with more than 7 colours for example and perfectly balanced. is it needed to change all these color faders to get your solution working ?  i mean i see you sliding just 1 fader,and it does the job , but that is because it is a simple gradient. if i understand it right , then i need to move all the 7 color faders as well to make this solution work? or ?

Comment: in my thinking i thought there would be a separate new node for this matter, such like the mapping node where you can rotate the gradient.

Comment: The colors may be able to be set by just three faders, if it is in the order of the rainbow. However you may just need to add more points. You can set the position exactly by typing a value into the *Pos* slider. Click a fader to select it, plus button to add, etc. Hope that helps :D

Comment: i was looking for a solution with a similar node like the mapping node,where you can rotate the color ramp,by just changing a value.i don't want to touch and replace the color points in the ramp.if moving the color faders is the only option,i will just forget about it,and leave it as it was, but it would just be cool to have a convenient mapping node where i can do it exactly in the way how i want to convenient change a value and see it change when i slide with the numbers on the fader.just like i would do rotation value ,same idea. easy handling,and no changing inside my colorramp itself

Comment: Wait, what? What do you mean by rotate the color ramp?

Comment: what i mean is that i can add a new node if i like to rotate the colorramp, all i have to do is to add a simple mapping node, and change the rotation value. in this case i don't have to touch the color positions on the gradient it self. just the value does the work , nice and easy. now for the tiling in this answer it seems that i need to mess up with the positions of the colorpoints in the gradients , but i was looking for a node such as the mapping one ,that i can use for a rotating task . a simple value that i can change to tile the gradient, and make the colours repeat as much as i need.

Comment: The color points are just what range of colors you want to use. The mapping node will tell the orientation, and the Math > Modulo node tells it to repeat. Copy my node setup exactly and tell me if it works.

Comment: @elmentor If this worked, please accept the answer to show a satisfactory solution has been found.