# How to make the Black pattern repeated on the ring? Resolved

Tags: texturing, shader-nodes

The black color pattern only shows on the front and back. What method could make it shown on the left and right sides? The black part is made with a colorramp node and controlled by a vector map in size and position.
Thanks for your time to review and answer my question.
[image]

Update 01-21
This is my result from using the node set-up.
[image]

Comment: There was a similar question here https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/26889/115533

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I repeat a gradient color ramp?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26889/how-do-i-repeat-a-gradient-color-ramp)

Comment: Thanks, guys! However, this setup does not work for me. I got weird results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple setup using *Gradient Texture*'s *Radial* option.

[image]

As long as you land on an integer for the value it should distribute evenly.

[image]

Comment: Hi Allen, the method works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I did adjustments to my situation based on Allen's node setup.

[image]